# Use a signal to update different tables

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I have the members, colors, groups, members_colors, members_groups and colors_groups tables. The members, colors, groups and colors_groups tables alredy have the needed registers but I need that when a register is added to the members_groups table automatically check the colors asigned for that group and then add registers to the members_colors table with the member especified in members_groups table and the colors asigned for the group that the member belongs.

I think to do that with a post_save signal using members_groups as sender but I cannot figure how.

**EDIT:** I use the default `User` model from django and this is my `models.py` file:

```
class Colors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Groups(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Groups_Colors(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Groups, related_name='gc_group', null=True, blank=True)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Colors, related_name='gc_color', null=True, blank=True)

class Users_Colors(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='uc_user', null=True, blank=True)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Colors, related_name='uc_color', null=True, blank=True)

class Groups_Users(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Groups, related_name='gu_group', null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='gu_user', null=True, blank=True)
```

What I want is when a register in `Groups_Users` is added, automatically update the `Users_Colors` table using as reference the data in `Groups_Users` to take the values from `Groups_Colors` and `User`.

**EDIT 2** Thanks to @ilse2005 I can get the signal work like I want. Here's the signal if someone need something alike:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Groups_Users, dispatch_uid='signal_receiver') 
def signal_receiver(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    group = instance.group
    user = instance.user
    colors = Groups_Colors.objects.filter(group_id=group).values_list('color_id',flat=True)
    for color in colors:
        Users_Colors.objects.create(user_id=user, color_id = color)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#post-save) Signal. Add this to your `models.py`:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

#sender is the Model after which save method the signal is called
@receiver(post_save, sender=Groups_Users) 
def signal_receiver(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # instance is the new GroupUsers
    group = instance.group
    user = instance.user
    # loop over Group_colors and create User_Colors
    for color in group.gc_color.all():
        Users_Colors.objects.create(user=user, color.color)
```

Comment: I get that but the part I cannot figure is the logic in the `#do the stuff you want` part.

Comment: Hm. Don't really understand what you want. Could you post your models?

Comment: Ok I posted the models.

Comment: Edited my answer. Not sure if it is 100% what you want, but should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you so much @ilse2005